# PHP Popup Page show content of records in db

Tags: php

I have links on a PHP page where it lists all records from a database.

The links look like this:

`<a href="http://domain.com?id=1">View Records</a>` <--ID at the end

What I want to do it to click on that link and option a popup what shows all fields from id 1

What's the easiest way to show all fields where id=1 on a popup when I click the link?

For example: I have a table like this:

```
id | name | surname
--------------------
1  | Bob  | brown
2  | Ken  | blob
```

and I click on a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://domain.com?id=1">View Records</a>
```

I need a popup to open and display something like this:

```
ID - 1
Name - Bob
Surname - Brown
```

Comment: Which part? There's a lot of pieces to this and you haven't said what you're working with. The 'easiest' way to do something is to re-use what you already have.

Comment: You mean all records from a table with id 1?

Comment: Please see update for further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very rudimentary example of one (of many ways) to popup a window::

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="window.open('http://domain.com/popup.php?id=1', 'View','width=300,height=200,menubar=yes,status=yes')">View Records</a>
```

**popup.php:**

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("my_database", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myID=".$_GET['id']);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo 'ID - '.$row['id'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Name - '.$row['name'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Surname - '.$row['surname'] . '<br/>';
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: All considerations of using mysql_* and input validation/scrubbing should be applied of course.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thanks